# Apache ActiveMQ Classic support life cycle

Tags: activemq-classic

I'm looking for a help with identifying an official support life cycle for Apache ActiveMQ Classic.

The [ActiveMQ web site](https://activemq.apache.org/) states:

> Once Artemis reaches a sufficient level of feature parity with the "Classic" code-base it will become the next major version of ActiveMQ.

But how to translate this statement to a support time-frame? For example, what kind of support will Apache provide for the ActiveMQ Classic in the next 5 years? Are there LTS versions of ActiveMQ Classic?

Update: Looking at the [ActiveMQ download page](https://activemq.apache.org/components/classic/download/), it seems like some sort of release strategy is definitely in place. The page shows two active (and I presume currently supported) versions: 5.17 and 5.18. The older versions (e.g. 5.16) are marked as "older release". As well, the minor versions of the 5.17 were released after the 5.18 first release, i.e. 5.17 is still getting patches while the older releases (e.g. 5.16 are not patched anymore). This indicates that there is a support timeframe stated somewhere inside the Apache AMQ team. Otherwise, the patches wouldn't be released for 5.17.

A reference to an official document/statement from Apache in regards to this subject would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately the "official document/statement from Apache" is shipped with every piece of software that it provides, i.e. the [Apache License](https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0) which can be summarized, in part, as stating:

> Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.

Also, the [ActiveMQ website](https://activemq.apache.org/support) has specific details about support. In short, if you need something beyond the community support which is provided for free on a volunteer basis then I recommend you look at a commercial support option.

My individual assessment as a committer and a member of the ActiveMQ Project Management Committee is that there is a large base of ActiveMQ Classic deployments given it has been the de facto standard JMS server implementation for well over a decade. Many of these folks have migrated to ActiveMQ Artemis, but many are also perfectly content to stay on ActiveMQ Classic forever. The community has continued to produce releases with bug fixes and internal component upgrades (e.g. to address CVEs), and I imagine that will continue for the foreseeable future assuming there is demand.

Comment: You can find a similar statement in pretty much every open source product. Which does not prevent the committees of the product from publishing the releases plans. Look at the Postgres as an example.

Comment: Certainly the license doesn't preclude projects from publishing release plans, etc. I didn't mean to imply otherwise. However, every community is different - even between Apache projects. At Apache the individual community members are ultimately responsible for any support guarantees. To my knowledge, ActiveMQ has never tagged with releases with LTS or advertised support guarantees.

Comment: Thank you.  I would not expect the guarantees as there is no contract. But at lest the release plans could be shared, I think. Matt mentioned that some work in this regards is underway.

Comment: Just to clarify, what specifically do you mean when you say "release plans"? Are you talking about a schedule for when a particular release will occur? Something more than that? Please elaborate. Thanks!

Comment: I would like to see for how long a particular version will be supported i.e. receive enhancements and/or patches and the new versions release place. This is required to plan our upgrades accordingly. For example, if we know that the release 5.18 will not be supported after 2024, then should can plan our upgrade to some prior date and coordinate it with our internal plans for other products releases.

Answer (score 0):

The ActiveMQ 5.x release planning is underway. The JDK LTS, Jakarta, and ActiveMQ release alignment will be sorted out. As Justin mentioned, Apache is a volunteer organization, so its all best effort, but with such a long running history and wide user base, it is reasonable to expect users to continue on it for quite some time.

For stable release alignment plans, keep an eye on:

https://activemq.apache.org/components/classic/download/

https://activemq.apache.org/jms2

For commercial support check out:

https://activemq.apache.org/support

Comment: We've checked the support conditions with the RH as per the advice on the link provided. First of all, RH does not provide support for the Apache ActiveMQ installations. They do provide support for their products only which is not quite the same. If you install the Apache ActiveMQ, you cannot buy the RH support for this installation. Now, to the main point. RH completely ends support of AMQ v6 (which is based on the ActiveMQ 5) next year . Would it be reasonable to expect that Apache will stop supporting (enhancements, patches) of the ActiveMQ v5 at about the same time?

Comment: Red Hat doesn't directly influence what is or isn't supported by the Apache ActiveMQ project. I do not believe it is reasonable to expect the ActiveMQ community to stop supporting the "Classic" broker when Red Hat's AMQ 6 reaches its ultimate EOL. The two are not correlated. I would expect the ActiveMQ community to continue to produce "Classic" releases with bug fixes and component upgrades for the foreseeable future assuming there is demand.

Comment: Similar to other popular open source projects, there are several other companies providing support for ActiveMQ 5.x and contributing to the ActiveMQ 5.x development for the foreseeable future. See the support link for a list.

Comment: I've updated my question with additional consideration. It seems like the release and support strategy exists and ActiveMQ is following the strategy.  I just cannot find the document.